# Finitely generated modules of associated graded algebras

Tags: modules, representation-theory

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional simple Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ be its Cartan subalgebra (or maximal toral subalgebra). We know that the universal enveloping algebra $U$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ admits a filtration given by $U^0 \subset U^1 \subset......\subset U^n \subset....$ (where $U^0 = \mathbb{C}$ and $U^n$ is generated by all the products $x_1....x_k (x_i \in \mathfrak{g}$ and $k \leq n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$)) and consequently we have an associated graded algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ denoted by $grU = \bigoplus_{n \in Z_{+}} \dfrac{U^n}{U^{n-1}}$ (where $U^{-1}=(0)$ and $Z_{+}$ is the set of all non-negative integers).

Now $\mathfrak{g}$ acts on $U$ via $x.u=x.u-u.x$ which is the nothing but the action induced from the adjoint action of $\mathfrak{g}$ on itself. Under this action, $\mathfrak{h}$ acts diagonally on $U$ and thus we have a decomposition of $U$ given by $U= \bigoplus_{\beta \in Q} U_{\beta}$
where $Q$ $(\subset \mathfrak{h^{*}})$ is the root lattice of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $U_{\beta}=\{u \in U: h.u = \beta(h)u$ $\forall h \in \mathfrak{h}\}$. Note that for any $\beta \in Q$, $U_{\beta}$ acts on $U_0 (0\in Q)$ both as a left module as well as a right module.

Moreover note that $\mathfrak{h}$ preserves the above filtration of $U$ and hence acts diagonally also on $grU$. Consequently, we also have a decomposition of $grU$ given by $grU = \bigoplus_{\beta \in Q} (grU)_{\beta}$ where $(grU)_{\beta}=\{u \in grU: h.u = \beta(h)u$ $\forall h \in \mathfrak{h}\}$. Again observe that for any $\beta \in Q$, $(grU)_{\beta}$ acts on $(grU)_0(0 \in Q)$ both as a left module as well as a right module.

Now $\bf assume$ that for any $\beta \in Q$, $(grU)_{\beta}$ is a finitely generated $(grU)_0$-module. Then is it true that $U_{\beta}$ is a finitely generated  $U_0$-module ?

I guess that the assertion is true as many properties that hold good in case of the associated graded algebra carry over to the original algebra, but I am not able to prove it rigorously.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but since you only consider the vector space structure of $U$ and $gr U$ ($U_0 = \mathbb{C} \cong (gr U)_0$ ), it seems to me that you have an isomorphism $U \to gr U$ (by choosing a basis compatible with the filtration) which maps $U_\beta$ into $(gr U)_\beta$. Consequently, if the latter is finitely generated, then so would be the former, or am I missing something?

Comment: First of all, I apologize for my choice of bad notation. I have fixed it now. Why is $(grdU)_0$ isomorhic to $\mathbb{C}$? By $U_0$, do you mean $U^0$ in my corrected notation? If that is the case, then ok. But it seems like you mean $U_0$ in the given decomposition of $U$ where $0 \in Q$. In that case $U_0$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$. If you need some more clarification, do let me know about it. Thank you.

Comment: I am not only using the vector space structures on $U$ and $grU$, but also the fact that both $U$ and $grU$ are both $Q$-graded algebras over $\mathbb{C}$ to finally get the $U_0$ module structure on $U_{\beta}$ and the $(grU)_0$ module structure on $(grU)_{\beta}$ repectively.

Comment: If you meant $(grdU)_0$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ where $0 \in {Z_+}$, then you are right. But if you are taking $0 \in Q$, then the statement is not true.

Comment: I see, it is as you suspected, I thought the index $U_0$ and $(gr U)_0$ came from the $Z_+$-grading. Thanks for clearing this up.